# Run methods based on a boolean value

Tags: java

Hello I would like to call a method when a boolean is true.
I tried this:

```
public void checkboxpress(int i){
    assert(day_b_1) ?  uncheckbox() : checkbox();
}
```

but this does not work. Ho can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: I find that the Java ternary operator lessens the maintainability of legacy code ;) and you should read up on Java naming conventions and etc.

Comment: I would advise that you familiarize yourself with Java a bit more than you apparently already have, or you will find yourself consistently frustrated by small, supposedly trivial tasks such as this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use an if statement -- don't try to be fancy (KISS -- Keep It Simple, Silly).

```
if (day_b_1) uncheckbox();
else checkbox();
```

now if both those methods return a result you can do

`result = day_b_1 ? uncheckbox() : checkbox();`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad -- yeah, I like being super nice...;)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply check if it is true:

```
if(day_b_1)
   uncheckbox();   // if day_b_1 is true uncheck
else
   checkbox();
```